# Elegant way to iterate 2 items at a time through object that implements Iterator

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm using `phpQuery` to parse a some `HTML` that have a similar to this structure:

```
<div>
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>John</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>23</span>
    <span>Location</span>
    <span>London</span>
</div>
```

I need to collect all this information into an associative array, so I'm doing something like this:

```
$doc = new phpQuery($html);
foreach($doc['div span'] as $span){
    $text = pq($span)->text();
    // do some other stuff with $text
}
```

Note that `$doc` and `$doc['div span']` are `phpQueryObject`s that implement `Iterator`, `Countable` and `ArrayAccess`.

Now, to correlate this data, I'm forced to use a variable where I store the current state (title or value) which is not quite elegant. What I would like to do is to be able to iterate 2 items at a time. One solution I found was to do iterate through all the object using `foreach` adding all the items to an array and after that just use `next()` or `each()` on that array to get 2 items at a time in a while loop, but this is not nice at all. Keep in mind that using `next()` or `each()` on a `phpQuery` object I just get it's public properties and that's not what I want at all. Is there a way to do this and have a nice code?

---

Note: Although this question is related to `phpQuery`, I think it's a general `php` question and does not involve `phpQuery` knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question, `phpQuery` implements `Iterator`.

So I'd say this is probably the cleanest way you can do what you want:

```
$doc = new phpQuery($html);
$elements = $doc['div span'];

foreach($elements as $span){
    $key = pq($span)->text();
    $elements->next();
    $value = pq($elements->current())->text();
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Depending on your PHP version, you may have to break this into 2 lines: `$val = pq($doc['div span']->current())->text();`

Comment: I'll slightly edit this answer (if you don't mind) and then will accept it :)

Comment: It also implements `ArrayAccess` so I needed to put this `$doc['div span']` into a variable